# C# - How do I read text between an unkown number of commas?

Tags: c#, count, console

I hope you're all doing well. I'll try to keep myself short so let me give you an example right away.

Let's say that I have two lists. In the first list there are different words on different lines. In the second list there are synonyms for each and every word.

List 1:

```
hello
exhausted
happy
```

List 2:

```
hi, hey, howdy
beat, foreworn
glad
```

The console application outputs a random line number's string from the first list and then it let's me enter a synonym. After this, the console app checks if the synonym that I stated is within the same line number but in list 2.

I would like to count how many letters there are before, in between and after the commas.

Can anyone help? I'm far from a professional when it comes to C# so if anyone thinks I should rewrite the lists in any different way to make it easier I would be happy to do so.

Thanks!

Edit: The reason I want to do this is because if the console outputs "hello" for example, all it takes for the player is to enter "h" and it counts as correct. This is because there is an H in "hi" (see list 2). If I knew how many letters there are between the commas then the console would be able to give the player a wrong if the input's characters is more or less than the number of characters in list 2.

Comment: can you explain this line with example? and why do you want to do this? I would like to count how many letters there are before, in between and after the commas.

Answer (score 0):

Split your string..

```
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;

  // ....

  bool CheckSynonym(List<string> list1,List<string> list2, string provided, string synonymprovided)
    {
        if (list1.IndexOf(provided)<0) return false;
        if (list1.IndexOf(provided)>=list2.Count) return false;
        string s = list2[list1.IndexOf(provided)];
         List<string> lstwords = s.Split( new char[] { ',' } ).ToList();
        if (lstwords.IndexOf(" "+synonymprovided) >= 0) return true;
        if (lstwords.IndexOf(synonymprovided) >= 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

This could work fine.. but I'd like to make a remark about the way you store your data. You stated *"After this, the console app checks if the synonym that I stated is within the same line number but in list 2."*

When you are going to expand your synonym dictionary, this is not handy, because you will have to check line numbers. I would use a single list, to include the words in the first list, like so

```
List:

hello, hi, hey, howdy
exhausted, beat, foreworn
happy, glad
```

Code can be straightforward, like

```
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;

  // ....

  bool CheckSynonym(List<string> list, string provided, string synonymprovided)
    {
        foreach (string s in list) 
            {
                List<string> lstwords = s.Split( new char[] { ',' } ).ToList();
                if  (lstwords.IndexOf(provided ) == 0)
                  if (lstwords.IndexOf(synonymprovided) > 0) return true;
                    else if (lstwords.IndexOf(" " + synonymprovided) >= 0) return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Note: this second solution allows for a single list.. but it will be slower !

Answer (score 0):

One possible method:

```
string x1 = "hi, hey, howdy";
x1.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Trim().ToCharArray().Count()));
```

Prints
2,
3,
5